# Is it possible to do systems programming in J or something close to it?

Tags: j, systems-programming

just wondering if this is possible? if so id like to see some online texts about it b/c I googled and couldnt find any haha, thanks

Comment: book about J , or Books about making systems with J

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to say no. While technically anything is possible, J will need its interpreter, so you've got at least that much to consider. J also has sluggish memory access time, making it not the ideal platform to do system programming.

So the real answer would be yes, it can, but it's far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean.

If you do not mind putting a j interpreter into your system (along with whatever dependencies it needs), you could do some systems programming.  However, the interpreter overhead would not be trivial, I imagine.

Traditionally, you would compile systems code, but no one has written a J compiler yet.  (And, a full implementation of J would require an interpreter in some cases -- but hypothetically speaking you would not have to code in a way which requires an interpeter.)